# Adaptive median filter with Opencv c++

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, opencv, codeblocks

I had a problem with writing the code of the adaptive median.

Which is the best way to compute the min intensity pixel max n median?

Til now I read every value of the pixels of the image

```
for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
{
   uchar *ptr = (uchar*)(img->imageData + y * step);
   for (int x = 0; x < w; x++){
    printf("%u, ", ptr[x]);
   } 
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: what's the problem? can you describe it with more details? have you checked your algorithm? what you got? what you expected to get? can you write some code?

Comment: Please ask a specific question. Where are you having trouble? Are you just looking for someone to convert your logic into code? If so, this isn't the site for it.

Comment: i managed to read every pixel in the image with my code so i want a suggestion which is the fastest way to pick the max value min value n median not for converting my algorithm to code of course

Answer (score 0):

For the maxima and minima in a rectangular window, I would look to [van Herk's dilation algorithm](http://www.google.hu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAB&url=http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.4.1969&rep=rep1&type=pdf&ei=LON9UODGCO7R4QSbtIHQBw&usg=AFQjCNHC92TOv9IS9hmcSA11BRMa2mX_rw&sig2=QLoEiEZHnsqdNzP3o_oVsw), as grayscale dilation corresponds to the maximum operator, and grayscale erosion to the minimum operator and a rectangular structuring element could be decomposed to a vertical and a horizontal line.

For the median filtering I would look to [moving histogram techniques](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/INF2310/v12/undervisningsmateriale/artikler/Huang-etal-median.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

For the min/max pixel you'll need to record the value of the first pixel and then compare each other pixel to it, storing the new value if it's lower/higher respectively. OpenCV provides the [cv::minmaxLoc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#minmaxloc) to make this easy.

For the median you'll need to sort all pixels and select the middle one (once sorted of course, finding the min/max is trivial as they'll be on either end of the list). This is more tricky, how far have you got and what is not working?